# Comparing list of unique objects with custom function

Tags: python, iteration

I need to **compare hundreds of objects** stored in a unique list to find duplicates:

```
object_list = {Object_01, Object_02, Object_03, Object_04, Object_05, ...}
```

I've written a custom function, which returns `True`, if the objects are equal and `False` if not:

```
object_01.compare(object_02)
>>> True
```

Compare method works well, but takes a lot of time per execution. I'm currently using `itertools.combinations(x, 2)` to **iterate through all combinations**. I've thought it's a good idea to use a dict for storing already compared objects and create new sets dynamically like:

```
dct = {'Compared': {}}
dct['Compared'] = set()

import itertools
for a, b in itertools.combinations(x, 2):

    if b.name not in dct['Compared']:

        if compare(a,b) == True:

            #print (a,b)
            key = a.name
            value = b.name

            if key not in dct:
                dct[key] = set()
                dct[key].add(value)
            else:
                dct[key].add(value)

            dct[key].add(key)

    dct['Compared'].add(b)
```

**Current Output:**

```
Compared: {'Object_02', 'Object_01', 'Object_03', 'Object_04', 'Object_05'}
Object_01: {'Object_02', 'Object_03', 'Object_01'}
Object_04: {'Object_05', 'Object_04'}
Object_05: {'Object_04'}
...
```

I would like to know: **Is there a faster way to iterate through all combinations** and how to *break/prevent* the iteration of an object, which is already assigned to a list of duplicates?

**Desired Output:**

```
Compared: {'Object_02', 'Object_01', 'Object_03', 'Object_04', 'Object_05'}
Object_01: {'Object_02', 'Object_03', 'Object_01'}
Object_04: {'Object_05', 'Object_04'}
...
```

**Note:** Compare method is a c-wrapper. Requirement is to find an algorithm around it.

Comment: what does compare check?

Comment: First question:  is `object_01.compare(object_02)` identical to `object_02.compare(object_01)` ?

Comment: @Izkata yes, result should be the same.

Comment: @poor, then so as I have added in the answer, use a tuple of attributes as the key, that will group all common objects

Comment: One possibility, if you can define `__hash__` you can use `set(x)` to get unique objects, then group the rest into one of those buckets.

Comment: Are you sure your output is correct?  `Object_01` includes itself, `Object_04` includes itself, `Object_05` does not include itself.  And why are `Object_04` and `Object_05` separate if 04 indicates it's the same as 05?

Comment: @Izkata Thanks. Good question: Included `Object_01` only to complete the set of duplicates, here: `dct[key].add(key)`. `Object_05` should not be generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to calculate all combinations, you just need to check if a given item is a duplicate:

```
for i, a in enumerate(x):
    if any(a.compare(b) for b in x[:i]):
        # a is a duplicate of an already seen item, so do something
```

This is still technically O(n^2), but you've cut out at least half the checks required, and should be a bit faster.

In short, `x[:i]` returns all items in the list before index `i`.  If the item `x[i]` appears in that list, you know it's a duplicate.  If not, there may be a duplicate *after* it in the list, but you worry about that when you get there.

Using `any` is also important here: if it finds any true item, it will immediately stop, without checking the rest of the iterable.

You could also improve the number of checks by removing known duplicates from the list you're checking against:

```
x_copy = x[:]
removed = 0
for i, a in enumerate(x):
    if any(a.compare(b) for b in x_copy[:i-removed]):
        del x_copy[i-removed]
        removed += 1
        # a is a duplicate of an already seen item, so do something
```

Note that we use a copy, to avoid changing the sequence we're iterating over, and we need to take account for the number of items we've removed when using indexes.

Next, we just need to figure out how to build the dictionary.

THis might be a little more complex.  The first step is to figure out exactly which element is a duplicate.  This can be done by realising `any` is just a wrapper around a `for` loop:

```
def any(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if item: return True
    return False
```

We can then make a minor change, and pass in a function:

```
def first(iterable, fn):
    for item in iterable:
        if fn(item): return item     
    return None
```

Now, we change our duplicate finder as follows:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

x_copy = x[:]
removed = 0
for i, a in enumerate(x):
    b = first(x_copy[:i-removed], a.compare):
    if b is not None:
        # b is the first occurring duplicate of a
        del x_copy[i-removed]
        removed += 1

        d[b.name].append(a)

     else:
         # we've not seen a yet, but might see it later
         d[a.name].append(a)
```

This will put every element in the list into a dict(-like).  If you only want the duplicates, it's then just a case of getting all the entries with a length greater than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Group the objects by name if you want to find the dups grouping by attributes

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,i,j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j


object_list = {Foo(1,2),Foo(3,4),Foo(1,2),Foo(3,4),Foo(5,6)}

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for obj in object_list:
    d[(obj.i,obj.j)].append(obj)

print(d)

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {(1, 2): [<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fa44ee7d098>, <__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fa44ee7d128>], 
(5, 6): [<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fa44ee7d1b8>], 
(3, 4): [<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fa44ee7d0e0>, <__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fa44ee7d170>]})
```

If not the name then use a tuple to store all the attributes you use to check for comparison.

Or sort the list by the attributes that matter and use groupby to group:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,i,j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
object_list = {Foo(1,2),Foo(3,4),Foo(1,2),Foo(3,4),Foo(5,6)}

from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter
groups = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(object_list, key=attrgetter("i","j")),key=attrgetter("i","j"))]

print(groups)

[[<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f794a944d40>, <__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f794a944dd0>], [<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f794a944d88>, <__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f794a944e18>], [<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f794a944e60>]]
```

You could also implement lt, eq and hash to make your objects sortable and hashable:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,i,j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.i, self.j) < (other.i, other.j)


    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.i,self.j))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.i, self.j) == (other.i, other.j)


print(set(object_list))

object_list.sort()
print(map(lambda x: (getattr(x,"i"),getattr(x,"j")),object_list))
set([<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fdff2fc08d0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fdff2fc09d0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fdff2fc0810>])
[(1, 2), (1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Obviously the attributes need to be hashable, if you had lists you could change to tuples etc..

Comment: @poor, add exactly what you are comparing to your question, as I said in a comment you can use a tuple of elements as the key but without knowing exactly how you are comparing I cannot add any more to the dict

Comment: I know what it returns. what I need to know is what attributes you compare, to use a set you would have to make your objects hashable which could be done but we need to see how what the attributes are. Did you look at the code in my answer and how I grouped the objects by attributes?

Comment: It's a combination of 2-3 API methods and unfortunately not standard python.

Comment: what do you mean by api methods? Can you add the it to the question as without knowing what you are comparing it is going to be impossible to help

Comment: Thanks for your effort and sorry Padraic. Maybe I should rephrase my question... I'll think about it. I'm only searching for a way to use MY compare function with a solid algorithm. +1

Comment: If you cannot group using  attributes whether by sorting or using the dict or make the objects hashable and just call set on the list then I think it is going to be hard to do anything efficient. I think adding the definition of compare would be more important than the code you have posted.

Comment: You are right, also your answer is great and makes sense in other cases. But as I mentioned, I don't have access to the compare function (in my case). Thanks again.