# How to remove duplicates from a list of custom objects in Python using a custom equality function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I succinctly remove duplicates from a `list` of custom objects using a custom equality function?

Many solutions relies on `set()` or the built-in `in` operator, but I can't guarantee that objects have defined `__eq__` or `__hash__`.

Can a solution be written more succintly using list comprehensions or other nifty tricks than my initial attempt?

```
l = [4, 9, 5, 1, 3, 1, 8, 9, 5, 4]
result = [] 

for n,i in enumerate(l):
    found=False
    for j in l[:n]:
        if (lambda a, b: a == b)(i,j): // or use a custom function
            found=True
            break
    if not found:
        result.append(i)

print(l)
print(result)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310542/comparing-list-of-unique-objects-with-custom-function

Comment: *"I can't guarantee that objects have defined `__eq__` or `__hash__`."* - They will have both by default unless they explicitly set them to `None`.  (Or if they explicitly define `__eq__` without defining `__hash__`, their `__hash__` will be implicitly `None`.)

Comment: Downvoting for hard to understand single letter variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[v1 for i, v1 in enumerate(l) if not any((v1 == v2 for v2 in l[:i]))]
```

Syntax can be abbreviated slightly if desired:

```
[v1 for i, v1 in enumerate(l) if not any(v1 == v2 for v2 in l[:i])]
```

I think that's fairly readable in itself, but if explanation is needed, it is filtering out items that compare equal to any previous item.

By using a generator comprehension as the argument to `any`, it is not necessary to test every item against every other item, where items are duplicated.  As soon as a matching item is found, `any` returns `True` and stops iterating, so the generator does not perform any further comparisons.  This is equivalent to doing a `break` from an explicit loop.

Comment: How can `any()` take `v1 == v2 for v2 in l[:i]` as an argument? If you `v1 == v2 for v2 in l[:i]` standalone, then you get a syntax error. What's the mechanism (language feature) used here?

Comment: @Shuzheng If you have a generator comprehension as the sole argument to a function, you are allowed to omit the outer parentheses. If you find that confusing, then use the first version, which explicitly includes them.

Comment: I see I need parentheses around `v1 == v2 for v2 in l[:i]`: `(v1 == v2 for v2 in l[:i])`, why is that needed? And why can it be left out in a function call?

Comment: @Shuzheng I guess that it is just a permitted shorthand because there is nothing that it could be confused with.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [4, 9, 5, 1, 3, 1, 8, 9, 5, 4]
result = [] 

for n,i in enumerate(l):
    if i not in result:
        result.append(i)
    else:
        continue
print(l)
print(result)
```

Comment: You don't need the `n == 0` special case.

Comment: I'm going to edit this to remove the special case -- hope that's okay with you. When `n == 0` (the first iteration) `result` is an empty list and `i not in result` will evaluate `True` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
it's not need to use enumerate:

```
l = [4, 9, 5, 1, 3, 1, 8, 9, 5, 4]
result = []

for i in l:
    if i not in result:
        result.append(i)
    else:
        continue
print(result)
```